# How to upload image from c# app to server (php file) with MyWebRequest

Tags: c#, php, winforms, webrequest

I Use MyWebRequest class to post information from c# app to server and connect with php file.

That is MyWebRequest class

```
    class MyWebRequest
    {
        private WebRequest request;
        private Stream dataStream;

        private string status;

        public String Status
        {
            get
            {
                return status;
            }
            set
            {
                status = value;
            }
        }

        public MyWebRequest(string url)
        {
            request = WebRequest.Create(url);
        }

        public MyWebRequest(string url, string method)
            : this(url)
        {

            if (method.Equals("GET") || method.Equals("POST"))
            {
                request.Method = method;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Invalid Method Type");
            }
        }

        public MyWebRequest(string url, string method, string data)
            : this(url, method)
        {
            string postData = data;
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
            dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            dataStream.Close();

        }

        public string GetResponse()
        {
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            this.Status = ((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription;
            dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
            reader.Close();
            dataStream.Close();
            response.Close();
            return responseFromServer;
        }
    }
```

In C# form:

```
            OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
            open.Filter = "Image Files(*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.bmp)|*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.bmp";
            if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                image.Image = new Bitmap(open.FileName);
                try
                {
                    Image image1 = Bitmap.FromFile(open.FileName);
                    image1 = resizeimage(image1, image.Size);
                    string saveimagename = editnumber.Text + "-" + propertycode.Text + ".bmp";
                    image1.Save(saveimagename, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
                    string pathname = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + saveimagename;
                    MyWebRequest uploadrequest = new MyWebRequest("http://mywebsitename/csharp.php", "POST", "Metod=Uploadfiles&Uploadtype=image&Filename=" + saveimagename + "&Pathname=" + pathname);
                    string uploadreq =  uploadrequest.GetResponse();
                    MessageBox.Show(uploadreq);
                }
                catch
                {
                    // Error Massage.
                }
            }
```

In csharp.php file :

```
if ($_POST["Metod"] == 'Uploadfiles'){

                if ($_POST["Uploadtype"] == 'image')
                {
                    $uploadDirectory = "./uploads/";
                    $pathname = $_POST["Pathname"];
                    $fileName = $_POST["Filename"];
                    $uploadPath = $uploadDirectory . $fileName; 
                    $didUpload = move_uploaded_file($pathname, $uploadPath);
                    if ($didUpload)
                    {
                        echo "Sucsess";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo "Erro In Upload Imgae.";
                    }
                }
            }
```

i check the size in c# but after the form load and press upload btn:

show: Erro In Upload Imgae. Massage.

i use MyWebRequest class in other forms and work correctly!!!

Comment: you do not pass `image1`bytes  to the `MyWebRequest` class and file is not send to the remote server. It looks like php code  accepts file path as an argument but it will work if file is under the web site root folder and client code (c# form) is executed on same server that host your web app.

Comment: You are also using `move_uploaded_file` wrong. This does not work with whatever arbitrary file path you throw at it as first parameter - it _checks_ if the file actually resulted from a file upload in the first place. You need to use the temporary path as PHP provides it within the $_FILES array.

Comment: my app don't have a host and database is offline i just want to save image online. i just check username online and that work correctly with mywebrequest class.

Comment: @polrealestate None of what you've just said has any relevance or forms any kind of useful response to the comments above. I suggest you find some tutorials / examples showing you a) how to send files using C# and b) how to receive files using PHP. Both are common tasks. You should be able to find plenty of examples and be able to use them in your app with minimal re-writing. Don't re-invent the wheel.